# ERROR:'Settings' object has no attribute 'NEO4J_DATABASES' when add neo4j db for django project

Tags: django, python-2.7, neo4j, neo4django

I want to have two Databases in my social network Django project one realtional and one graphbased.i choose Mysql and Neo4j.my `settings.py`file in my project is:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'mylife',                    
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
    'HOST': '',                     
    'PORT': '',                    
}
}

NEO4J_DATABSES = {
    'default':{
        'HOST':'localhost' ,
        'PORT':7474,
        'ENDPOINT':'db/data'
    }
}
```

i append `NEO4J_DATABSES` section according to [neo4django documents](https://neo4django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html) but when i run `pyhon manage.py syncdb` i got the below error:

```
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'NEO4J_DATABASES'
```

and when i write `python manage.py shell` to test something when i write these codes i got same error:

```
>>> from neo4django.db import models
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4django-0.1.8-py2.7.egg/neo4django     /db/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
if not _settings.NEO4J_DATABASES:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
return getattr(self._wrapped, name)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'NEO4J_DATABASES'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have it misspelled in your `settings.py`:

```
NEO4J_DATABSES
```

should be:

```
NEO4J_DATABASES
```

Comment: i don't know how thank you.thanks very much man :D.you are correct